# Image not resizable in with tailwind CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, astrojs

I have been working on Astro JS with Tailwind CSS. When I tried to change the provide width and height there seems to be no change in the width and height.

```
<div>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <img class="ml-auto w-108" src={bgimg} alt="Stop">
    <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 flex flex-col items-start pl-10 pt-10">
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-black mt-56 ml-10">Title</h1>
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-black mt-5 ml-10 text-orange">"Sub para"</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Also saw there is not style for `img` tag over the project. The above code is in `landing.astro` file where it's resued in `index.astro` file. But Another image file is resizable `<img class="w-20 h-20" src={logo} alt="Logo">` with this code.

Comment: You probably need to set `width` and `height` **attributes** on the `img` element. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Images_in_HTML#width_and_height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to create the desired width, just write w-[108px] and write the value inside [width].
Finally, the Tailwind compiler does the work and creates the desired class with a width of 108 pixels.

```html
<div>
    <Navbar></Navbar>
    <img class="ml-auto w-[108px]" src={bgimg} alt="Stop">
    <div class="absolute top-0 left-0 flex flex-col items-start pl-10 pt-10">
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-black mt-56 ml-10">Title</h1>
        <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold text-black mt-5 ml-10 text-orange">"Sub para"</h1>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually it works. Thanks but even when I give 96 which is defined the image is still not resizing itself. But it works when I mention it in px. Can I know why this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

The class `w-108` is not a class that is included with Tailwind, the maximum default for all spacing is `96`. You can [add `108` as a custom size to your tailwind config](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width#customizing-your-theme), or use [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#using-arbitrary-values).

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/width

Comment: Also tried adding that but still doesn't work